# Jquery - How to prepend elemend before text in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my code in Jquery. I need to put one element before text in div. But it stays on same place. Can you help me ? Thank you very much.

Jquery:

```
$('.content_wrap img').each(function(){
   if($(this).nextAll('.darkblue').length !== 0){
      $('.darkblue').next('<div>').prepend($(this));
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<h2>
   <img class="catIcon" alt="Software Maintenance Agreements" src="http://www.example.com/storage/images/article/21-80-3.jpg" style="padding-right: 10px;"> <!-- this is image i want to move before text -->
   <a class="darkblue underline ui-link" href="http://www.example.com/gb/en/2099_software-maintenance-agreements-sma.html?do=article">Software Maintenance Agreements (SMA)</a>
</h2>
<div>
Software Maintenance A...roups at a fixed rate. <!-- element should appear before text -->
   <a class="small ui-link" href="http://www.example.com/gb/en/2099_software-maintenance-agreements-sma.html?do=article">[more..]</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('.content_wrap img').each(function () {
    $(this).prependTo($(this).parent().next())
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6hdEv/)

---

If you want to check whether the next element has the class darkblue then

```
$('.content_wrap img').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.next().hasClass('darkblue')) {
        $this.prependTo($this.parent().next())
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6hdEv/2/)

Comment: You're missing the check for the existence of the `darkblue` link

Answer (score 2):

why not just try

```
$("div").prepend($this)
```

if that's the only div in your file.

Comment: then just give this one a specific id like <div id="addcontent">...... </div> and then use the format:
$("#addcontent").prepend($this)
This would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the parent of `nextblue` (the `h2`) then find the next div:

```
$('.content_wrap img').each(function(){
   if($(this).nextAll('.darkblue').length !== 0){
      $('.darkblue').closest("h2").next('div').prepend($(this));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find it's parent's next div not it's next div:

```
$('.content_wrap img').each(function(){
   if($(this).nextAll('.darkblue').length !== 0){
       $('.darkblue').parent().next().prepend($(this));
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

working Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/avi_sagi/P6LhK/

The `<h2>` must be inside `<a>` tag. I checked with the Updated code its fine

```
<div class="content_wrap">
    <img class="catIcon" alt="Software Maintenance Agreements" src="http://www.example.com/storage/images/article/21-80-3.jpg" style="padding-right: 10px;">
    <a class="darkblue underline ui-link" href="http://www.example.com/gb/en/2099_software-maintenance-agreements-sma.html?do=article">
        <h2>Software Maintenance Agreements (SMA)</h2>
    </a>

    <div>Software Maintenance A...roups at a fixed rate.
        <a class="small ui-link" href="http://www.example.com/gb/en/2099_software-maintenance-agreements-sma.html?do=article">[more..]</a>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.darkblue').parent("h2").next("div").prepend($(this));
```